# sys open not working with pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have :
Now if instead of `input` in `sys_open()`, if I were to pass a.txt, it works. But I need to get the username for command line therefore I have to copy it to `input`. when I pass my pointer variable, it does not work. Why?

```
int main()
{
    char *name;

    char input[1024];
    strcpy(input, argv[1]);

    name = input;

    sys_open(input, "O_RDWR", 00700);

}
```

Comment: What is the signature of sys_open()?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: No error, its just not doing its job.

Comment: @Sibrajas sys_open(const char * filename, int flags, int mode)
AdeelAhmed the fileid is returning negative

Comment: `if (sys_open(input, "O_RDWR", 00700) < 0) {
    perror("sys_open");
}` Try this to find out why sys_open is returning negative number..

Comment: Because it needs a const char *, my input is in a char input[], how would I convert it into const char * ?

Comment: Just typecast it, as @Ganesh mentioned..

Comment: I did, did not work. I typed casted the array, should I type cast the pointer poiniting to the array?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but why are you `malloc`'ing 100 bytes, and then discarding it? That's a leak, at best, but I'm betting it's not doing what you expect at all.

Answer (score 3):

The flags to `open` (I'm not sure why you're referring to it as `sys_open`) are passed as a symbolic constant, not a string.

```
open(input, O_RDWR, 00777);
```

You will almost certainly need to assign the return value somewhere to do anything useful.

Comment: I know that, and I have that logic done already. Like I said, when I pass "a.txt" instead of input, or any file name, it works!

Comment: please help me out here, the parameter is const char * and I am taking input in a char []

Comment: `char[]` (actually `char *`) is automatically cast to `const char *`. There is nothing additional that you need to do. With the `O_RDWR` change made and the necessary `#include`s added, your code works fine for me.

Comment: If so, you have probably failed to include `fcntl.h`. Do that. Also, you need in general to be more specific about the problems you're having. "Doesn't work" or "causes an error" is far too vague. **Be specific.**

Comment: What you are failing to comprehend is MY LOGIC WORKS when I pass a string literal, such as "abc.txt", only when I pass the char array does it not work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with `sys_open(input, O_RDWR, 00777);`. I have modified this code as below and it is working for me

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char *name;
int   fd;
int   data = 0;

char input[1024];
strcpy(input, argv[1]);

//name = input;
fd = open((const char *)(input), O_RDWR, 00700);
printf("file descriptor: %x\n", fd);

read(fd, &data, 2);
printf("Data: %d\n", data);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same thing, does not work. it works if I pass "a.txt" as input, but if its in a variable of pointer, or char[] it does not work.

Comment: `open` takes a first argument as const char *. Hence, when you pass a.txt, the code works, whereas when char * is passed, the open doesn't give the desired results

Comment: how would I convert a char arra y into const char * ?

Comment: Please try `sys_open((const char *)(input), "O_RDWR", 00777);`.

Comment: I tried on Mingw environment. The following code is working for me
`fd = open((const char *)(input), O_RDWR, 00700);` followed by a read as `read(fd, &data, 2);`